# Numpad number keys output 789456123 when 123456789 is the input respectively

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

Got gnome on arch linux, a strange issue popped up recently, when numlock is on, the numpad number keys output 7 8 9 4 5 6 1 2 3 when 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 is the input respectively, like it does on a phone keypad, but this a fullsized mechanical keyboard I'm talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Check out gnome-tweak-tool, you might have set the numeric keypad style to 'ATM/Phone' style

Comment: Your self-answer is technically correct, but it would be more helpful to others with the same problem if you could expand it a little to explain how to do it.  Thanks.